# Why 7 padding fields in Disruptor, but 6 fields in Mechanical Sympathy - False sharing

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile, false-sharing

In LMAX-Exchange/Disruptor 3.4.3, [RingBuffer](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/RingBuffer.java) put 7 long padding fields (via extends **RingBufferPad**) before its really fields

```
abstract class RingBufferPad
{
    protected long p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7;
}
```

and put another 7 long padding fields at the end to avoid false sharing

```
public final class RingBuffer<E> extends RingBufferFields<E> implements Cursored, EventSequencer<E>, EventSink<E>
{
    public static final long INITIAL_CURSOR_VALUE = Sequence.INITIAL_VALUE;
    protected long p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7;
```

The question is why putting 7 long padding fields, not 6 fields as described in [Mechanical Sympathy - False Sharing](https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/07/false-sharing.html).

```
public final static class VolatileLong
{
    public volatile long value = 0L;
    public long p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6; // comment out
}
```

Comment: If you look at the comment section of the linked article, many people suggest that having only 6 padding variables is wrong and that p7 is missing.